# How can maven enforce use of supported GWT source in builds for GWT module's dependency builds?

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-compiler

My GWT module depends on my SDK module.  I want to block commits of java language features unsupported in GWT.

For example, GWT doesn't support **Arrays.copyOf** and when someone adds this to SDK, SDK builds fine but down the line GWT fails.

How can I fail on these early so I don't run through a long build before discovering the incompatibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

GWT can do that by running the compiler with `-validateOnly`, but this is [not supported by the org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-297). You should be able to do that with the exec-maven-plugin though.
(**EDIT:** Ray Cromwell [confirms that it should work](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/szTw5q4BaBc/discussion); it'll also check the `JavaScriptObject` restrictions: protected constructor, no field, all methods `final`)

Side note: that's probably something I should add to the net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin's gwt-lib packaging (to become the official GWT maven plugin). I've filed [an issue about it](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin/issues/4).